# olympiad question from team selection test on the sums of fourth powers of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This question is from the second selection test for the second JBMO 1998.

> Find the smallest value of $n$ for which there exist the positive integers $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$ so that $$x_{1}^4+x_{2}^4+\ldots+x_{n}^4 = 1998$$

In the book solution, it says

> Observe that for any integer $x$ we have $x^4 = 16k$ or $x^4 = 16k + 1$.
>
> As $1998 = 16(124) + 14$, it follows that $n \geq 14$.

How did it get to the conclusion that $n \geq 14$? Just because a number is of the form $16k$, that doesn’t mean it is a fourth power of some integer. Even if $16(124)$ could be expressed as some $x_{i}^4$ and the remaining $14$ covered by repeating $(1^4)$ $14$ times wouldn’t that mean $n \geq 15$? Does anybody have another way of solving this?

Comment: Can you tell me which book you took this solution from?

Comment: The goal is to limit the search space rather than to provide an immediate answer to the question. The modulo $16$ congruence is an easy way of doing that. It also tells you that you need $14$ or $30$ or $46$ or ... ($\equiv 14 \bmod 16$) odd fourth powers in your sum

Comment: I got this problem from the book "The Junior Balkan Math Olympiads" by Dan Branzei, Ioan Serdean, and Vasile Serdean. the problem is problem number 30 from section 2.2, the second selection test for the second JBMO 1998.

Comment: @MarkBennet, since $x^4 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$ or $1 \bmod 5$ can't we use the same logic to get that the number of fourth powers congruent to $1 \bmod 5$ is a number $k$ with $k \equiv 3 \bmod 5$? How can this be used to solve the problem?

Comment: I already read the answers below. This problem, I must say,--as far as for a math olympiad--hardly seems that interesting, as $7^4 > 1998$. So you just have to find $n=\sum_{i=1}^6 a_ii^4 = 1998$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^6 a_i$ is minimized. So it seems plausible that some brute force would find the smallest integer $n$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already know that $n\ge 14$.

Suppose that $n=14$ works.

Then, as nonuser's answer says, all $x_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots, 14)$ have to be odd, so $x_i^4=1,81,625$.

Let $a$ be the number of $x_i^4$ such that $x_i^4\equiv 1\pmod{10}$.

Let $b$ be the number of $x_i^4$ such that $x_i^4\equiv 5\pmod{10}$.

Then, we have $a+b=14$ and $a+5b\equiv 8\pmod{10}$, so we have $4b\equiv 4\pmod{10}$, so $b=1,6,11$.

- $b=1$ is impossible since $1998=x_1^4+\cdots +x_{14}^4\le 625+13\times 81=1678\lt 1998$.
- $b=6,11$ are impossible since $1998=x_1^4+\cdots +x_{14}^4\ge 6\times 625=3750\gt 1998$.

So, we can say that $n\not=14$.

$n=15$ works since we have
$$3\times 1^4+1\times 2^4+9\times 3^4+2\times 5^4=1998$$

Therefore, the smallest value of $n$ is $\color{red}{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

Say $a$ of the numbers $x_1^4,x_2^4...$ are of form $16k$ and $b$ of form $16k+1$. Then $$1998 = 16(...)+ b$$

So $b\geq 14$ so $n=a+b\geq 14$.

Comment: I have a question: suppose $a$ of the numbers are of form $5k$ and $b$ are of form $5k+1$ so that $1998= 5(\dots) + b$. So $b\geq 3$? What importance does $16$ here have?

Comment: From what I have understood I think it's because $x^4 \equiv 0\mod16$ (if x is even) or $x^4 \equiv 1\mod16$ (if x is odd) for all integers $x$. So then we can say there are $a$ even $x_{i}$ and $b$ odd $x_{i}$ and then continue as above.

Comment: My computer search yields that there isn't even a solution with $n=14$.

Answer (score 1):

The text you quote from the book is not a complete solution. It is just a first step. In the comments below your question you yourself suggest a similar, smaller first step; reducing mod $5$. Indeed mod $5$ you have $x^4\equiv0,1\pmod{5}$ for any integer $x$, and so
$$x_1^4+\ldots+x_n^4=1998\equiv3\pmod{5},$$
shows that $k\geq3$. A larger modulus could give you a stronger lower bound on $k$, and a sensible candidate modulus is $16=2^4$ because it is the largest modulus that has only two possible residues for fourth powers. That is, it is the largest integer $m$ with $x^4\equiv0,1\pmod{m}$ for all integers $x$. And so you find that
$$x_1^4+\ldots+x_n^4=1998\equiv14\pmod{16},$$
and so $n\geq14$. This shows that every solution must have $n\geq14$. It does not show that a solution with $n=14$ exists!

To fully answer the question we must find the least positive integer $n$ for which a solution exists; we have just shown that $n\geq14$. Let's try to construct a solution with $n=14$. There are not many fourth powers to consider, as $7^4=2401>1998$ and so $x_k^4\in\{1,16,81,256,625,1296\}$ for all $k$. Let $c_k$ denote the number of times the fourth power $k^4$ occurs in our sum. Then $n=c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5+c_6$ and
$$1998=c_1\cdot1^4+c_2\cdot2^4+c_3\cdot3^4+c_4\cdot4^4+c_5\cdot5^4+c_6\cdot6^4,$$
and reducing mod $16$ shows that $c_1+c_3+c_5\geq14$. So to get $n=14$ we must have $c_2=c_4=c_6=0$. We see that $c_5\leq\frac{1998}{5^4}<4$, and because
$$c_1\cdot1^4+c_3\cdot3^4+c_5\cdot5^4=1998\equiv3\pmod{5},$$
we see that $c_1+c_3\equiv3\pmod{5}$ and so $c_5\equiv1\pmod{5}$, so $c_5=1$. But then
$$c_1\cdot1^4+c_3\cdot3^4+c_5\cdot5^4\leq0\cdot1^4+13\cdot3^4+1\cdot5^4=1678<1998,$$
a contradiction. So there is no solution with $n=14$.

Next let's try to construct a solution with $n=15$. As before we find that $c_5<4$ and $c_1+c_3+c_5\geq14$, and so either $c_2=1$ or $c_4=1$ or $c_6=1$. Reducing mod $5$ now shows that $c_1+c_3\equiv2\pmod{5}$ and so $c_5\equiv2\pmod{5}$, so $c_5=2$ and $c_1+c_3=12$. Then
$$(12-c_3)\cdot1^4+c_2\cdot2^4+c_3\cdot3^4+c_4\cdot4^4+2\cdot5^4+c_6\cdot6^4=1998,$$
which immediately shows that $c_6=0$. Then $c_2=1$ or $c_4=1$. If $c_2=1$ then we are left with
$$(12-c_3)\cdot1^4+1\cdot2^4+c_3\cdot3^4+0\cdot4^4+2\cdot5^4+0\cdot6^4=1998,$$
which has a solution $c_3=8$. On the other hand, if $c_4=1$ then $c_2=0$ and we are left with
$$(12-c_3)\cdot1^4+0\cdot2^4+c_3\cdot3^4+1\cdot4^4+2\cdot5^4+0\cdot6^4=1998,$$
which has a solution $c_3=6$. Either way we see that there is a solution for $n=15$.