# Why choose $\bmod 16$ to solve this number theory problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I'm interested in this problem, which was asked earlier on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840331/olympiad-question-from-team-selection-test-on-the-sums-of-fourth-powers-of-numbe), but these results of mine lead me to questions rather than answers, so I'll ask them here instead.

> Find the least $n$ such that $$x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+\dots+x_n^4 = 1998$$ where $x_i \in Z^+$.

Solution:

> Since $\bmod 16: x^4 \equiv 0 \lor 1 \ \ \forall x \in Z$, it follows we can write the $4$th power numbers either as $16k$ or as $16k+1$. Now since $16(124)+14 = 1998$, the minimum value of $n$ is $14$.

In the solution, it is implicitly assumed that for $1998$ to be attained, you'd need zero $4$th powers of form $16k$ and $14$ such of form $16k+1$. $(♡)$

My question is: why $\bmod 16$? If I chose $5$, which too has quartic residues $1,0$, I'd get $5(399)+3$ so $1998$ should be achievable whenever there are $3$ numbers of form $5k+1$.

**My work**:

Of course, both lines of reasoning mentioned priorly, with $16$ and $5$ don't actually *prove* that $\min n=14$ or $\min n = 3$. They only show that $n\geq 14$ or $n \geq 3$. Now to show that the equality, one has to do some tedious algebra.

First it is clear that, $7^4>1998$, and also from $(♡)$ that $\bmod 16: x^4\equiv 1 \implies x\equiv 1\lor 3\lor 5$. So $x \in \{1,3,5\}$. We see that $5^4$ may be repeated either twice or thrice and in both cases it becomes easy to verify that $1988$ is never achieved with our assumption $(♡)$.

If we forget that assumption, we get that $x \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We can again suppose $1998 = a\cdot 6^4 +b \cdot 5^4 + c\cdot 4^4 +d\cdot 3^4+e\cdot 2^4+f$ where $0\le a \le 1$, $0\le 
b \le 3$, $0\le c \le 7$, $0\le d,e,f \le 14$.

A quick computer search shows $1998 = 2\cdot 5^4 + 9\cdot 3^4 + 2^4+ 3$ is at $n=15$ which is the least we can go (if I wrote my python code correct).

So, this assumption $(♡)$ was incorrect, and in fact the solution appears to be incorrect.

So, how did the author choose $\bmod 16$ and even if he did, is the solution presented even correct? What would be the correct approach to solve this?

I regret having to open a somewhat "duplicate" post, but I have more questions than answers so I apologize.

Comment: As you remark, these arguments are incomplete.  $16$ is clearly an attractive choice as it gives a respectably large minimum, but a priori even that minimum might be unrealizable.

Comment: As you observed, 5 is also a reasonable choice. In this case, trying either 5 or 16 would make sense. One doesn't give you as much information, so then trying the other is a good tactic.

Comment: I agree. I don't think there exists any value for a solution for $n=14$ (unless I made a mistake), I've written a code to verify that. But for whoever was taking this exam and solving the problem in $1998$, I doubt calculators would have been allowed. It evades me how to solve this without very tedious and long calculations.

Comment: Worth noting that the greedy algorithm, just take out the largest fourth power you can at each stage, yields a sum of $19$ terms..so not helpful.  I agree that yours is minimal, but I too just did a search.

Comment: Wrong solutions to a problem are a scandal :)

Comment: @lulu you can refine the greedy algorithm approach slightly if you're aiming for a particular $n$. The mod $16$ approach tells you $n\ge 14$; you can prove that $n=14$ doesn't work; then if you try $n=15$ you can get an answer, and a greedy algorithm helps a bit there. But I am wondering if there was either a typo in this question or another relevant question on the original paper.

Comment: @ChrisLewis  Thanks for those remarks...I agree with you that the question must have been misstated.   Maybe we're all missing some quick step, but I kind of doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your first question, $16$ is a good choice because it's the largest number with only two quartic residues (trivially, any modulo larger than this must have at least $0$, $1$ and $16$ as residues). Being large means it gives you a lot of information.

The more interesting point is that, no, it's not possible to write $1998$ as a sum of $14$ fourth powers. This, at least, is actually fairly easy to prove.

Following the reasoning you mentioned, since $1998\equiv 14 \pmod{16}$, if we were to be able to write $1998$ as a sum of fourth powers, every one of those powers would have to be odd. Since $7^4=2401>1998$, the only fourth powers that can contribute to the sum are $1^4=1$, $3^4=81$ and $5^4=625$; ie we must have
$$1998=a+81b+625c$$
where $a+b+c=14$. But, as you noticed, modulo $5$ is also useful. We'd need
$$3\equiv a+b \pmod 5$$
so that $c = 14-a-b \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. But $c$ can't be more than $3$, otherwise $625c$ would be greater than $1998$. So we would have to have $c=1$.

But then $a+b=13$ and $a+81b=1998-625=1373$. Subtracting,
$$80b=1373-13=1360$$
whose solution is $b=17$; ie too large.

I suppose the original question expects solvers to first establish $14$ as a lower bound for $n$, then prove it's not actually attainable (with something like the above), then try $n=15$ using a greedy algorithm approach, but it does seem a bit hard.

For reference, there are, in fact, two solutions with $n=15$:
$$1998=3\cdot 1+16+9\cdot 81+2\cdot 625=6\cdot 1+6\cdot 81+256+2\cdot 625$$

---

I'm not convinced the original question was expecting this, but just to outline how you might find solutions for $n=15$ without a calculator: first, let's note that from the mod $16$ work, if a solution with $n=15$ exists, then exactly one of the fourth powers is even. Whichever one we choose, it will have a residue of $1$ modulo $5$.

So now we're looking for a solution to
$$1998=16k^4+a+81b+625c$$
with $a+b+c=14$ and $k\in\{1,2,3\}$.

We can substitute $a=14-b-c$ to get
$$1984=16k^4+80b+624c$$
and divide through by $16$:
$$124=k^4+5b+39c$$

Now, $5(b+c) = 124-k^4-34c$; since $0\le b+c\le 14$, we have
$$0\le 124-k^4-34c \le 70$$

Rearranging,
$$\frac{54-k^4}{34} \le c \le \frac{124-k^4}{34}$$

The best I can come up with here is casework: if $k=1$, we have
$$\frac{53}{34}\le c \le \frac{123}{34}$$
so that $c=2$ or $c=3$.

If $k=2$, we again find $c=2$ or $c=3$.

If $k=3$, $c=0$ or $c=1$.

These values can be substituted in to find the two solutions given above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would be really glad if you could elaborate on finding those two solutions, or what way one should use for the same. I don’t see how the greedy algorithm could be employed here.

Comment: I didn't really get anything nice for those solutions - the only way I used a greedy algorithm was to keep trying the largest fourth powers that wouldn't go over $1998$. The only helpful observation I had was that, if you're trying to achieve the total with $n=15$, exactly one of the fourth powers is even. So you can just try those, but that seems very inelegant to me. I wonder if there were other related questions on the paper?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a non-calculator way to find those solutions. The point where I divided by $16$ makes the numbers a lot more manageable (there are lots of approaches you could use from there - more modular arithmetic might reduce the case count further, but $6$ seemed doable). The main issue I have with this question is that, if you were doing this as an exam, there's no guarantee that $15$ is the right answer, so this approach would be pretty daunting.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll accept this answer, and try to investigate any relevant context of this problem.